# Refresh token with Graph OAuth v2.0

Tags: javascript, angular, microsoft-graph-api, hello.js

I'm requesting a user's info via Microsoft Graph. I use the 2.0 endpoint.

This is my login function:

```
login() {
    hello('msft').login({scope: Configs.scope}).then(
      () => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.meService.getMe().subscribe(data => {
              localStorage.setItem('username', data.mail);
              localStorage.setItem('jobtitle', data.jobTitle);
              localStorage.setItem('loggedin', 'yes');
            },
            err => {
            console.log(err);
            },
            () => {
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            });
        });
      },
      e => console.error(e.error.message)
    );
  }
```

This is my init function:

```
initAuth() {
    this.redirect_uri = window.location.href;
    hello.init({
        msft: {
          id: Configs.appId,
          oauth: {
            version: 2,
            auth: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
          },
          scope_delim: ' ',
          form: false
        },
      },
      {redirect_uri: window.location.href}
    );
  }
```

And here I am getting the access token:

```
getAccessToken() {
    const msft = hello('msft').getAuthResponse();
    console.log(msft);
    const accessToken = msft.access_token;
    return accessToken;
  }
```

I get an access token, via which I can login. However, I get no refresh token. From what I read, you get the refresh and the access token via the /token endpoint. As far as I can see, I only use the /authorize endpoint and it works?

This poses a problem. I can't refresh my token!

A response looks like this:

```
access_token:
"This is private, but it's a very long string"
client_id:"e6c987d2-8bdc-4f1a-bafc-04ba3d51f340"
display:"popup"
expires:1524649746.548
expires_in:3599
network:"msft"
redirect_uri:"http://localhost:4200/"
scope:"basic,User.Read"
session_state:"89a68bd2-5ae5-4df2-88d0-d28718fd10bc"
state:""
token_type:"Bearer"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the [Implicit grant](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-implicit-grant), you cannot use Refresh Tokens. They're only supported using the [Authorization Code grant](https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer).

In order to use Refresh Tokens, you'll need to switch to the Authorization Code grant and implement the server-side code to process the authorization code into an access token. You'll also need to request the scope `offline_access` which triggers the generation of a `refresh_token`.